# Pipe output with tee & grep into file but seeing full output

Tags: linux, shell, grep, tee

Trying to get the output of a grep written into a file while having the by grep non-affected output in terminal.

Example:

command:

```
cat file | grep 'aaa' >> any.txt #Missing parameters here
```

desired output in terminal:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

redirected into any.txt

```
aaa
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please make the question more self explanatory?.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Tried to simplify it a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then maybe not grep, you can use `awk` instead:

```
cat file | awk '/aaa/{print >>"output.txt";}1'
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, can I somehow have that affect the entire line while not knowing what's inside the whole document?

Comment: f.e. knowing that the line i want somewhere includes aaa but it's not the entire line

Comment: @JaBush  Pardon, I don't understand you.

Comment: Nevermind, your comment already exactly solved what i needed. I expected it to work like "grep -o" which only greps the given text, but what you wrote grabs the entire line which includes the searched term.

Comment: @JaBush If you want it to work like `grep -o`, you can use `gsub` or `match` first, and then `print`. Try to find and read documents of `awk`, you'll find it powerful :)